# Terraform OCI Error in function call the "map" function was deprecated in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

Why do I get the following error?

Using Terraform and following the official published guide [here](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/oracle-terraform-modules/iam/oci/latest/submodules/iam-compartment) I'm trying to create a simple compartment on OCI and get the following error:

> │ Error: Error in function call │  │   on
> .terraform/modules/iam_compartment/modules/iam-compartment/main.tf
> line 36, in locals: │   36:   parent_compartment_ids =
> concat(flatten(data.oci_identity_compartments.this.*.compartments),
> list(map("compartment_id", ""))) │  │ Call to function "map" failed:
> the "map" function was deprecated in Terraform v0.12 and is no longer
> available; use tomap({ ... }) syntax to write a literal map.

**My terraform main.tf file:**

```
module "iam_compartment" {
  source                  = "oracle-terraform-modules/iam/oci//modules/iam-compartment"
  version = "2.0.1"
  tenancy_ocid            = var.provider.tenancy_id
  compartment_id          = var.provider.tenancy_id
  compartment_name        = "tf_example_compartment"
  compartment_description = "compartment created by terraform"
  compartment_create      = true
  enable_delete           = true
}
```

Version:

> Terraform v1.1.3 on darwin_amd64
>
> - provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/oci v4.59.0
> - provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0

Steps to recreate

- terraform init
- terraform plan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module you are using is not up to date with the latest Terraform version. Moreover, it contains code which is is not forward compatible.

As the error says, the `map` function in Terraform was deprecated in favor of `tomap` function. If we take a look at the source code for the module on [GitHub](https://github.com/oracle-terraform-modules/terraform-oci-iam/blob/f64a054b639bba44d01f5ef1b4342f5724f0a6a1/modules/iam-compartment/main.tf#L35), it is using using `map` function:

```
locals {
  compartment_ids        = concat(flatten(data.oci_identity_compartments.this.*.compartments), list(map("id", "")))
  parent_compartment_ids = concat(flatten(data.oci_identity_compartments.this.*.compartments), list(map("compartment_id", "")))
}
```

Also, there is an [issue](https://github.com/oracle-terraform-modules/terraform-oci-iam/issues/26) reported for this problem, without any recent activity.

Since, this module is from a third party, what you can do is to fork it on GitHub and fix change `map` function to `tomap`. Potentially, you could create  pull request with the fix.

Other option would be to get rid of this module, and build the its functionality yourself.